# Javascript remove lines containing the same numbers

Tags: javascript

If I have these lines, for example:

- 11 12 13
- 13 12 11
- 12 11 13
- 12 12 12

How could I remove lines, which has the same numbers (first 3 lines on my example) and leave only one of these lines?

The example lines after script should be like:

- 11 12 13
- 12 12 12

I have no idea how to even do this I really need help for this.

I have tried to sort and filter and this is what I got...

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltoycjae/1

I am using this sort and filter function from another guy of SO

```
function sortByFrequencyAndRemoveDuplicates(array) {
    var frequency = {}, value;

    // compute frequencies of each value
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        value = array[i];
        if(value in frequency) {
            frequency[value]++;
        }
        else {
            frequency[value] = 1;
        }
    }

    // make array from the frequency object to de-duplicate
    var uniques = [];
    for(value in frequency) {
        uniques.push(value);
    }

    // sort the uniques array in descending order by frequency
    function compareFrequency(a, b) {
        return frequency[b] - frequency[a];
    }

    return uniques.sort(compareFrequency);
}
```

Comment: How are stored those numbers ? Did you try anything ?

Comment: Sort and Filter, if they are in an array..

Comment: Split by space (the line), once in array sort and filter.

Comment: On textarea line by line. I will make a jsfiddle in a sec. I've tried to match duplicate lines with regex, but I think that was stupid idea even to try.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I just tried to filter and sort, but still can't get what I need https://jsfiddle.net/Ltoycjae/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use split and array sort functionality of JS like this

```
var arr = [
             '11 12 13'
            ,'11 12 13'
            ,'13 12 11'
            ,'12 13 11'
            ,'12 12 12'
            ];
    keys = [];        


function getKey(s) {
    return s.split(' ').sort().join('-')
}        

for (var i in arr){
    var key = getKey(arr[i]);
    if (keys.indexOf(key)==-1){
        keys.push(key);
        console.log(arr[i])
    }
}
```

you can run it here https://repl.it/Bl1i/0

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks mate, it helped a tone! I made the full working version here to split to array from  textarea https://jsfiddle.net/Ltoycjae/2/